# What happens when an rvalue reference is captured by copy?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

If I have

```
std::function<int()> &&x = [] { return 1; };
auto lambda = [y = x(), x] { 
    return y * x();
};
```

What is the type of `x` inside `lambda`: `std::function<int()>`, `std::function<int()>&` or `std::function<int()>&&`? And if the first, is the captured `x` initialized by the move constructor, or by the copy one (and I need `[y = x(), x = std::move(x)]` to move it instead)?

Comment: Looks like `const std::function<int ()>` from the forced compiler error - live - https://godbolt.org/z/Pfh5z9K8G

Comment: Am I mistaken or is it in fact a `std::function<int()>&&`? [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hX27tYDUreTee002).

Comment: 1. It'll be `std::function<int()>`. 2. Yes you need to write `x = std::move(x)` explicitly.

Comment: @2b-t Answered below.

Comment: @songyuanyao Thanks, I already upvoted it. Playing around with simple example I already found out that `decltype` in there actually returns the local `variable` as capturing the variable by reference would not do anything. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the type of `x` inside `lambda`

`x` is captured by-copy, and the type of data member declared in the closure type would be `std::function<int()>`. [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.capture#10)

(emphasis mine)

> For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is
> declared in the closure type. ... **The type of such a data member is the referenced type
> if the entity is a reference to an object**, ...

And

> is the captured `x` initialized by the move constructor, or by the copy one (and I need `[y = x(), x = std::move(x)]` to move it instead)?

Yes, you have to write `x = std::move(x)` explicitly, otherwise `x` would be copy-constructed since the captured object `x` is an lvalue itself.

And about why `decltype(x)` leads to the type `std::function<int()>&&`, because `x` here refers to the local variable `x` defined before the lambda. [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.capture#11)

(emphasis mine)

> Every id-expression within the compound-statement of a
> lambda-expression that is an odr-use of an entity captured by copy is
> transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of
> the closure type.
>
> [Note 7: **An id-expression that is not an odr-use refers to the
> original entity, never to a member of the closure type.** However, such
> an id-expression can still cause the implicit capture of the entity. —
> end note]

BTW `(x)` is not an *id-expression* and `x` here refers to the member of the closure type. Then `decltype((x))` leads to type `const std::function<int()> &` (because `(x)` is an lvalue expression and `operator()` of the lambda is const-qualified; for `mutable` lambda it would be `std::function<int()> &`).

Answer (score 2):

`x` is captured by value, using the copy constructor.

The "type of `x`" is a bit moot. The class member of the lambda class has type `std::function<int()>`, so not a reference. The expression `x` has type `const std::function<int()>`, and is an lvalue. (It's `const` because we're inside of a const-qualified `operator()`. It's not a reference because expressions, unlike variables, [can't have reference types](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1).)

Example:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int &&x = 42;
    auto lambda = [x]
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<decltype((x)), const int&>::value, "");
    };

    static_assert(sizeof lambda == sizeof(int), "");
}
```

Clang & MSVC agree with the first assertion, while GCC thinks that the type is `int &`. I believe this to be a GCC bug in `decltype`.

All three compilers agree with the second assertion. Since all three compilers were tested on a platform where `sizeof(void*) > sizeof(int)`, it means all three of them copied the variable instead of storing a reference.

Comment: Will `decltype((x))` (unlike `decltype(x)`) not always return an `lvalue`?

Comment: @2b-t If you mean "an lvalue reference", then the answer is no. `&` is returned for lvalues, `&&` for xvalues, and non-reference types for prvalues.

Comment: I meant an `lvalue reference`. I am not sure what information `decltype((x))` should give you at this point... Will `x` in this case not just be the variable `x` outside the lambda as songyuanyao pointed out? This means in your case it will always return you an `lvalue reference` right no matter if `x` is `int&&` or `int`?

Comment: @2b-t `(x)` should refer to the capture, not to the original reference. *"what information `decltype((x))` should give you"* It tells me that `x` is const. If `x` was captured by reference, it would be non-const.

Comment: @2b-t `x` is an *id-expression*, so it refers to the original entity, while `(x)` is not an *id-expression*. So `decltype(x)` and `decltype((x))` give different result (`std::function<int()>&&` vs `const std::function<int()> &`). BTW for `mutable` lambda `decltype((x))` would be `std::function<int()> &`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Perfectly clear now, I thought `(x)` would be an id-expression too. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to language lawyer this, but [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6z68E7h68) is some playground code. It looks like clang and gcc assume an rvalue reference while msvc assumes a value without reference qualifiers.

However, in all cases, your object will be copy constructed.